# Android How to use WifiManeger Class startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested) function?

Tags: android, wifi, hidden, sony, sony-xperia

Android wifiManager.java file have startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested) function but it is Hidden function.

```
     * @hide
 */
public boolean startCustomizedScan(ScanSettings requested) {
    try {
        mService.startScan(requested, null);
        return true;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I must use this function. Request a scan for access points in specified channel list. Each channel is specified by its frequency in MHz, e.g. "2400"

Sony developer Web Page told the solution to this Link : http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/code-examples-using-hidden-android-apis/

But I Download your he hidden API code examples. Open the project in eclipse Tethering Demo project. but I have some errors.

```
[2015-07-29 14:19:17 – TetheringDemo] Uploading TetheringDemo.apk onto device ‘192.168.56.101:5555'
[2015-07-29 14:19:17 – TetheringDemo] Installing TetheringDemo.apk…
[2015-07-29 14:19:18 – TetheringDemo] Installation error:INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE
[2015-07-29 14:19:18 – TetheringDemo] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2015-07-29 14:19:18 – TetheringDemo] Launch canceled!
```

Please someone give me some insight in Sony sample project or other method.

Thanks!